# How can one change the OneDrive folder without having to log out of OneDrive?

Tags: window, onedrive

One way to change the Microsoft OneDrive folder is to [unlink](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/move-onedrive-folder) one's account:

[image]

How can one change the OneDrive folder without having to log out of OneDrive on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: Does `Choose Folders` not allow you to select folders and files, located in other directories?

Comment: @Ramhound no it only allows the user to select which folders in already present in OneDrive should be added to the computer.

Comment: I assume you are attempting to avoid having to download the contents of OneDrive account twice.  The problem is, even if you were to find a way to change the folder without unlinking it, you would still begin that download.  Do I assume correctly?